# TransactionScope and Distributed Transaction Coordinator on Oracle

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, distributed-transactions

I know how to implement a distributed transaction when executing queries across two MSSQL DBs using the DTC and the `TransactionScope` class. Are there infrastructure options available for Oracle on Windows and Oracle on *nix that provide the same service and would work with the same code, E.G.:

```
        try
        {
            using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
            using (var connection1 = new SqlConnection("{conectionString1}"))
            using (var connection2 = new SqlConnection("{connectionString2"))
            {
                var command = connection1.CreateCommand();

                command.CommandText = "insert into test values ('TEST') select @@identity";

                connection1.Open();

                var newRowId = command.ExecuteScalar();

                Console.WriteLine("Inserted new row in connection 1 with ID : {0}", newRowId);
                //transaction promoted on second connection open
                connection2.Open();

                command = connection2.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "set identity_insert TEST on";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText = string.Format("insert into test (Id, Text) values ({0},'TEST')", newRowId);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("Inserted new row in connection 2");

                transactionScope.Complete();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Transaction commited");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transaction rolled back");
        }
```

Comment: Oracle can participate in DTC-based transactions... what do you mean by "Oracle on Unix" ?

Comment: do you mean the code (i.e. Mono) OR do you mean the DB-server running on *nix ?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now; The code will always run on the .NET CLR (never Mono) but the database may be Oracle on *nix.

Comment: ok... as I already wrote in my first comment: Oracle-DBs (whether the server is on Windows or *nix does not make a difference) can be part of DTC-based transactions... what exactly is your question ?

Comment: oh I see.  I had assumed, because the DTC on Windows is separate from MSSQL, that there would need to be a *nix DTC server, but if I understand what you are telling me; the DTC is built into Oracle and thus works regardless of the OS. Thanks.

Comment: What I am telling you is that DTC support for Oracle comes with the Oracle client you install on the Windows machine running the C# code... how easy/hard it is to integrate Oracle with DTC depends on the Oracle DB provider you use (among other things).